# Variable locality in OpenMP Reduction with Fortran

Tags: fortran, openmp

This is a part of my Fortran code.

```
iabcd=0
!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(PRIVATE) SHARED(icheck,iv,HO,tnljm,H)
!$OMP DO SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC) REDUCTION(+: iabcd)
do ia=1,HO%NLEV 
  do ib=ia+1,HO%NLEV
    do ic=1,HO%NLEV
      do id=ic+1,HO%NLEV
        if(tnljm%t(ia)+tnljm%t(ib) .ne. tnljm%t(ic)+tnljm%t(id)) cycle 
        iabcd = iabcd + 1
        H%ka(iabcd) = ia
        H%kb(iabcd) = ib
        H%kc(iabcd) = ic
        H%kd(iabcd) = id
        H%ME2BM(iabcd) = 0.d0
      enddo
    enddo
  enddo
enddo
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

I can run the code without any warning. But, the results are weird and different from the results by not using the OpenMP. What's the problem with the code? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should come up with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain a bit what your code should be doing if it is not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `OMP DO REDUCTION(+:iabc)`, each thread creates its own private variable `iabc` and uses that one within the loop, only after the parallel region has been handled, the addition will take place.

That is, the access

```
        H%ka(iabcd) = ia
        H%kb(iabcd) = ib
        H%kc(iabcd) = ic
        H%kd(iabcd) = id
        H%ME2BM(iabcd) = 0.d0
```

only uses the local, private version of `iabc`, which is not the same behaviour as in the serial version of the code.

What you instead can do is to use `OMP CRITICAL` for the update of `iabc`, as you want all threads to use the same version of `iabc` (and of course, also make `iabc` shared). You then also have to create a private copy of `iabc` inside the critical region, such that the update of `H` happens with the correct `iabc`. This will however decrease the efficiency of the parallelization, unless `tnljm%t(ia)+tnljm%t(ib) .ne. tnljm%t(ic)+tnljm%t(id)` is almost always true.